# Trouble with Scala's class and object

Tags: java, scala, class, object

I am having trouble with finding the issue in my Scala code. Task below.

```
Input: val team1: Team = new Team(8,6) 
       val team2: Team = new Team(6,4)

Output for 'play' method: team1.score = 4
                          team2.score = 0

Output for 'Winner' method: team1
```

Task:

Create a Scala class named "Team" and a Scala object named "Referee".

Team will have:

•State values of type Int representing the strength of team's offense and defense with a constructor to set these values. The parameters for the constructor should be offense then defense

•A third state variable named "score" of type Int

Referee will have:

•A method named "play" that takes two Team objects as parameters and does not return a value. This method will alter the state of each input Team by setting their scores equal to their offense minus the other Team's defense. If a Team's offense is less than the other Team's defense their score should be 0 (no negative scores)

•A method named "Winner" that takes two Teams as parameters and returns the Team with the higher score. If both Teams have the same score, return a new Team object with offense and defense both set to 0

```
class Team(var offense: Int, var defense: Int){
      var score: Int = 0 //<-Updated Variable
}

object Referee{
def play(team1: Team, team2: Team) = {
    team1.score = team1.offense - team2.defense
    team2.score = team2.offense - team1.defense
    if (team1.offense < team2.defense){
    team1.score = 0
    }
    else if(team2.offense < team1.defense){
    team2.score = 0
    }
}
def Winner(team1: Team, team2: Team) = {
    if (team1.score > team2.score){
    team1
    }
    else if(team2.score > team1.score){
    team2
    }
    else{
    new Team(0, 0)
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assignments don't have return values. So you're creating a new `Team`, and assigning it to the variable `p`, and then throwing it away.

Remove the `val p =` part.

Comment: This doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: What exactly is "the problem"? With that little change your code compiles without error for me.

Comment: Then debug it. You haven't posted any test cases, example input, expected output.  Without that we just have to assume that the code is doing what it's supposed to do.

Comment: I updated my code. I think the score variable is supposed to be placed in the class Team. Still having trouble getting the correct value.

Comment: Debugging is a royal pain, but _everyone_ who writes code has to learn how to do it. `println()` is the first tool in your toolbox.

Comment: Just added the inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: Code is producing the expected outputs for me.

Comment: One question: how do I println my code to make sure it works? What did you try to get the expected output?

Comment: That's 2 questions. #1) Use `println()` to learn what's going on inside of methods that are returning unexpected values. #2) I created the 2 teams, passed them to `Referee.play()` and examined their altered `score` values. Then I passed the teams to `Referee.Winner()` and examined what was returned.

Answer (score 2):

The "task" that you set is inherently non-functional so it doesn't sit well with Scala. Just for fun, here is a more functional approach to the problem which avoids any mutable values:

```
case class Team(offense: Int, defense: Int) {
  def score(other: Team): Int = Math.max(0, offense - other.defense)
}

case class TeamScore(team: Team, score: Int) {
  def beats(other: TeamScore): Boolean = score > other.score
}

case class Result(score1: TeamScore, score2: TeamScore) {
  def winner: Option[Team] =
    if (score1 beats score2) {
      Some(score1.team)
    } else if (score2 beats score1) {
      Some(score2.team)
    } else {
      None
    }
}

object Referee {
  def play(team1: Team, team2: Team): Result =
    Result(
      TeamScore(team1, team1.score(team2)),
      TeamScore(team2, team2.score(team1))
    )
}
```